# Sonarqube : How remove the (outdated copy) message from a Quality Profile?

Tags: sonarqube

I have installed `sonarqube` for the version `7.0`. 
Previously in other directory I have installed the `6.1` version too. 
Thus exists two directories.

I did do the upgrade without any problems, it was mandatory when I have started for first time the `7.0`:

[image]

The situation is that appears the following:

[image]

How I can fix or remove the `(outdated copy)` message?

If I go to `Quality Profiles` option available in the top of the page, I can see the following:

[image]

and then if I select the *blue gear* I get the following:

[image]

I can't find some option to do an update.

From the same figure shown above, If I do click in `Sonar way (outdated copy)` link I go to (see below that *blue gear* is selected too)

[image]

And again I can't find some option to do an update.

If I go to `Marketplace` and click in `Updates Only` I can see just the following

[image]

Thus How I can fix or remove the `(outdated copy)` message?

**Alpha**

Other questions:

- Why appears two profiles from the beginning? (It for `Java`)
- Is possible use both together profiles for a scan process? (Has sense?)
- How know if there are more profiles available to be installed? Where and How? (I thought all come from `Marketplace`)

According with the figure see that the `outdated copy` profile has `312` rules against the other that has `295`. Thus in a first glance seems the former is better than the latter because has more rules, my the purpose of my post is apply the approach (if is possible) if I do click in some place and the profile gets update (and not removed) and thus the `outdated copy` message disappears.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you simply want to remove "(outdated copy)" from the name of this quality profile, simply click on "Rename" and choose a unique name for your quality profile.

If you want to get rid of this outdated copy, you have to change the default quality profile to be the "Sonar way" built-in one (or another one) before SonarQube allows you to delete the outdated copy.

Comment: The second approach seems more logical, but see `Alpha` section added. Thanks